# Why "shining" becomes "shin" after lemmatized using python nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, stem

there are several words that use "-ing" as present continuous like "shining". but when I try to lemmatize "shining" using nltk, it changes into "shin". the code is this:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
word = "shining"

newlemma = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word,'v')
print newlemma
```

even without using 'v', it still the same "shining" and doesn't change.
I'm expecting output "shine".
anybody can help? thanks

Comment: I don't get, what are you expecting as output?

Comment: I am expecting output "shine"

Comment: Looks like the lemmatiser isn't perfect. Did you find more errors of this kind?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way WordNet applies rules and exception lists when searching for the root form.

It has a list of rules particularly to remove word endings, for instance:

```
"ing" -> ""
"ing" -> "e"
```

It applies the rules and see if the resulting word form exists in WordNet. So for instance, with `mining`, it would try `min` and not find anything. Then it would try `mine` (second rule) and find `mine` is valid word and return it. But with `shining`, it likely tries `shin`, finds `shin` in the list of valid words and believes this to be the proper root, so it returns it.